# O(1) find value from a key in a range

Tags: data-structures, language-agnostic, range, key-value

What kind of data structure would allow me to get a corresponding value from a given key in a set of ordered range-like keys, **where my key is not necessarily in the set**.

Consider, [key, value]:

```
[3, 1]
[5, 2]
[10, 3]
```

Looking up 3 or 4 would return 1, 5 - 9 would return 2 and 10 would return 3. The **ranges** are **not constant sized**.

O(1) or *like*-O(1) is important, if possible.

Comment: For *arbitrary keys* I doubt there is such thing in a classical computer. There is only two possibilities 1) That O(log n) is like-O(1) for you 2) That there is a computable pattern in the keys (e.g. constant strides) and basically you fall back to an array-type storage.

Comment: This does not exist. You can make it logarithmic time, but never, ever constant time.

Answer (score 2):

A balanced binary search tree will give you O(log n).

Comment: Thanks, but I'm going to leave this open.

Comment: If you really want to optimize queries and you don't care about memory used and complexity of adding numbers then just keep an array of the size of the range. In each cell keep the value that should be returned. You will get O(1) queries this way, O(M) space where M is the range length and O(M) insertion time.

Comment: And if you make a ternary it's O(log3 n), and 4-tree is O(log4 n), and so on.

Answer (score 0):

what about a key-indexed array? Say, you know your keys are below 1000, you can simply fill a `int[1000]` with values, like this:
[0,0]
[1,0]
[2,0]
[3,1]
[4,1]
[5,2]
......
and so on. that'll give you o(1) performance, but huge memory overhead.

otherwise, a hash table is the closest i know of. hope it helps.
edit: look up [red-black tree](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Red%E2%80%93black_tree), it's a self balancing tree which has a worst case of o
(logn) in searching.

Comment: Unfortunately the keys are memory addresses, so it would be too much memory.

Answer (score -2):

I would use i Dictionary in this scenario. Retrieving a value by using its key is very fast, close to O(1)

```
        Dictionary<int, int> myDictionary = new Dictionary<int, int>();
        myDictionary.Add(3,1);
        myDictionary.Add(5,2);
        myDictionary.Add(10,3);

        //If you know the key exists, you can use
        int value = myDictionary[3];

        //If you don't know if the key is in the dictionary - use the TryGetValue method
        int value;
        if (myDictionary.TryGetValue(3, out value))
        {
            //The key was found and the corresponding value is stored in "value" 
        }
```

For more info: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/xfhwa508.aspx